# How to build up an elasticsearch query in a better way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, elasticsearch, vue.js, elasticsearch-plugin

I am currently using the [elasticsearch helper](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js) to run queries on my elasticsearch database. Currently I am using vue.js to help build this application.

When I am paginating my results I use this query:

```
this.client.search({
        index: 'node',
        type: 'vakantie',
        from: 12 * index,
        size: this.size,
}).then(function (resp) {
    this.travels = resp.hits.hits;

    this.currentPage = index;
}.bind(this), function (err) {
    console.trace(err.message);
});
```

I also have an input box above my results that a user can type a search term into and it will instantly filter down results using this query:

```
index: 'node',
type: 'vakantie',
from: 0,
    size: this.size,
body: {                 
    query: {
        match_phrase_prefix: {
            title: {
                query: this.query,
                slop: 10,
                max_expansions: 50
            }
        }
    },
    highlight: {
        fields: {
            title: {}
        },
        pre_tags: ["<span class='highlight'>"],
        post_tags: ["</span>"]
    }
}
```

I have filters and sort methods in place as well, and I know how to use a query with elasticsearch to combine multiple search queries.

Obviously I don't want to write a search query for every combination of filter + input + sort possible. Is there a better way to build up my search queries than using a javascript object like this?

Hopefully I am getting my point across, I have a bit too much custom code to simply paste it here.

Comment: It is hard to tell from your description what you are looking for... A way to generalize the filter arguments? If so, where is the filter? Can you show input and expected output?